# moving through a list

Tags: prolog

Learning this very slowly... got some books today and they just plain suck..

so.. I'm trying to move X position through a list.. then return the remainder of the list.  Problem being I'm returning merely the element at that position rather than the list.  I believe my problem is either the base case or the unknown variable.  I'm also not 100% sure when the "_" should be used..

an explanation would be extremely helpful.. thanx in advance.

```
move([X|_],0,X).
move([X|XS],K,L) :- K>0,
    K1 is K-1, move(XS,K1,L).
```

Comment: I find "move" to be a rather misleading name for this operation. I'd call it e.g. get_tail/3.

Comment: @Kaarel: the idiomatic name for this predicate is `nth_tail`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base case should be `move(X,0,X)`.

`move([X|_],0,X)` will unify X with the single element at the head of the list.

Comment: so the "_" is saying the tail is present.. but not being used?  Thus the use of the term X which is the entire list w/o breaking into head and tail?

Comment: exactly - `X` by itself makes no statements about what it will match against and so will unify with the entire list. The `[X|_]` pattern will break down the structure of the list and cause X to unify with the head.